# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Web Application's [second moderator election](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

[image: Sathya]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/2).

Comment: Congrats to @Sathya he was a good choice!

Comment: @Fogest than you very much :-)

Comment: @Sathya: Congrats buddy. Welcome to moderator community.

Comment: @SivaCharan thank you!

Comment: Congratulations @Sathya.

Comment: @AlEverett thank you :-)

Comment: You guys are super lucky to have @Sathya for a mod - he does awesome, level-headed, and fair work, and as a huge plus, already has experience on Super User - I'm fortunate to have him on my diamond team.